# htaccess doesn't work in subfolder - xampp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a web server which the file systen looks like that:

```
  -webfiles:
     -main.php
     -uploader.php
     -uploads:
          -image1.jpg
          -image2.png
```

for some reason... if I put the htaccess file inside the uploads directory it doesn't work... but puting it in the webfiles directory it works.

The problem is that my htaccess contains:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .php
Options -ExecCGI
```

So it stops the main.php and uploader.php from running...
I want to avoid running php inside images(for security reasons), but canot put the htaccess inside the uploads folder - it is ingnored by the server..

Any Ideas?

Comment: Not allowing `.htaccess` in the uploads folder looks like a good idea: if someone manage to upload a `.htaccess` file and it is interpreted, bad things will happen. Could you post the relevant apache configuration ? You must have somewhere a [`AllowOverride None`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

Comment: 1. I check the extenstions of the files before I upload them.

2. I checked the httpd.conf and the AllowOvveride is All (so it must work.. right?)

How can I addHandler just to the uploads folder while the htaccess is in the webfiles folder?

Comment: Site specific configurations are usually in a sub folder, (`sites-available` on Debian) and the main httpd.conf / apache.conf will load them (with an `Include subfolder/*.conf`). I think you have one for your website which disallow `.htaccess`. This is where you should put your `AddHandler`. If not, we will need the apache configuration to help you.